# Winapi: Does reading and writing to the same file via different handles require flushing?

Tags: winapi

Say I have opened two file handles to the same file (in the same process, if that matters). On the first handle I perform writes, on the second handle I perform reads.

```
hFile1 = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

hFile2 = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

SetFilePointerEx(hFile1, ...); // seek to write position
WriteFile(hFile1, ... );

// is any barrier or flusing needed here?

SetFilePointerEx(hFile2, ...); // seek to read position
ReadFile(hFile2, ... );
```

Will the reads on `hFile2` always immediatly "see" all previous writes performed on `hFile1`, or is it necessary to flush the first handle?

Is the behavior documented anywhere?

Is the behavior the same when using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`?

Comment: you not need any barrier or flusing. the same with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. and you not need use `SetFilePointerEx` - this is extra call. use explicit offset in `WriteFile` / `ReadFile` instead

Comment: @RbMm: any reference for your answer? (I included SetFilePointerEx just to be clear that I'm doing random access)

Comment: this is based only on my internal knowledge. flush will be need only in case - you write data via buffered file handle and than read data via not buffered handle (with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`). or you use asynchronous handles (operation can be not complete when Write/ Read return). if you use the same buffered method (both buffered or both un buffered) and both synchronous handles - you not need any flush or barrier. and again `SetFilePointerEx` - extra and trash call

Comment: @RbMm thanks. If the access is asynchronous, to avoid flushing is it sufficient for the write to have completed prior to the read being initiated?

Comment: flushing - this is force write data to disk from cache. you need flushing only in case - one file handle not use cache (so read direct from disk) and another use cache (so write not just to disk, but to cache first). but if both say use buffers - it coherent - not need any flush at all. flush need if you afraid lost written data (if system suddenly shutdown). about asynchronous - data will be coherent - if you begin read after write complete. but write complete (in asynchronous case) not just after writefile return, but some late. so you need wait for write complete before read

Comment: I would put the question differently - when operation full completed - which else barrier you want before next operation on the same file object ? and no any "barrier" api/ioctls for files. flush need only in case different cache usage - one use and another not